# How to show all categories in menus in homepage in Magento 2.2.3?

Tags: admin, magento2.2.3

I have installed Magento 2.2.3 successfully completed.But I have created categories but it will not show on homepage menu.I don't know how to implement this task.Can you please help me?.Please check my screenshots.https://prnt.sc/j5x93f https://prnt.sc/j5x9g4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Include in Navigation Menu` to `yes`. That will do the job.

Also, make sure your categories fall under the `Default Category`. Then make sure `Default Category` is set correctly in the store configuration.

This is a [**good starting point**](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-menu-is-not-showing.html).  Please go through it. Please remember to google first if you come across any problem. There are lots of [useful search results](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=category%20not%20showing%20in%20menu%20magento%202&oq=category%20not%20showing%20in%20menu%20magento%202&aqs=chrome..69i57.6831j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for this issue.

Comment: where should I give?

Comment: Hi @ Rajeev K Tomy, where should I give? .Can you please help me?

Comment: @DileepKumar Please see my edit

Comment: Hi  @RajeevKTomy  can you please help me  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239630/want-to-display-label-or-respected-value-on-the-visual-swatch-attribute-at-layer

Answer (score 0):

You have to create categories under "Default Category", Because Default Category is root category and only categories listed under this will show on frontend

Comment: Hi @ Naveed,  I don't understand.How to find out this problem.Can you please help me?

Comment: @DileepKumar, you need to drag and drop your category(ies) in "Default Catgory". Like click on "OTC medicine" category and drop it under "Default Category". do same with other categories. Once you don it will show categories on frontend.