# Want to display label or respected value on the visual swatch attribute at Layered navigation?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, swatches, configurable-swatches

I have created size attribute with **visual swatch** field now in the fronted when we hover at option it is displaying the **value/s** for the users. Instead of changing to **text swatch** how to display the label (or) respected value on that size attribute in the **layered navigation**.

Please refer the below screenshot so that will get some idea.

could you please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add text in swatches then you should use "Text Swatch" instead of "Visual Swatch". Refer below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi @chintan instead of changing from visual swatch to text swatch is there any alternative way to do?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I don't know it for sure but maybe we can do it programmatically.

Comment: Then please update that here.

Answer (score 0):

You can override this file to your theme

vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/layered/renderer.phtml

and make changes.